# OnBackPressing exits app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm using the camera intent to take a picture and process the pixels.
This works good so far, but when I press the **Backbutton** to reinitialize the camera a second time the app crashes.

My app also closes when I start it and press **back** without taking a picture before.
I implemented a button that calls the intent and it has been no problem to take multiple pictures.

LogCat Log didn't show anything interesting. I guess this is something basic I missed so I don't post any code but my Onback method.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        openCamera();

    }
```

**EDIT**
removing

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

solved the closing problem...

Comment: If your app crashes, then it's in the logcat somewhere. Maybe you just have the wrong filter or are not looking in the right place. I suggest double checking.

Comment: It's not crashing, it's closing. Rainwork was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        openCamera();

    }
```

Because default behavour of backButton it's call finish() for Activity. And you CALL it then invoke super.onBackPressed()

Other words you call default back button, but you want to ovveride it and in code wich must ovveride default action first line you call DEFAULT back button action.

Answer (score 0):

Might wanna try:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
       {       
      backMethod();
       }

       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```